# SVN version used by XCode 3.2.5 - Unsupported working copy format

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, svn

I am running an SVN 1.6.11 server and I initially imported an XCode project on the server (i.e svn 1.6.11).

I have a developer who is using XCode 3.2.5. He seems to have managed to do an inital checkout without any issue but upon trying to check back in again he gets the following error:

> Error: 155021 (Unsupported working copy format) Description: This
>   client is too old to work with working copy
>   '/Users/mac2/Desktop/WhatItTakesREPO'.  You need to get a newer
>   Subversion client, or to downgrade this working copy. See
>   http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change for
>   details.

It sounds to me like the version of SVN he is using is too old to work with my server.

My question is, how to I find out which version of SVN XCode is using? (as it is my understanding it may be using a different binary to the otherwise installed SVN)

Secondly, will downgrading the server to an equivalent version solve this issue?

I know that downgrading the server is not the best solution but for various reasons, upgrading to XCode 4.2 or even upgrading SVN on the developers machine is not possible.

Comment: Has he touched his working copy with the command line client that comes with OS X? If so, the working copy has probably been upgraded to a newer version than XCode 3.2.5 can handle.

Comment: If you've installed the Command Line Tools/Unix Development Environment/whatever (the name changes with each version of Xcode), you can just run `/usr/bin/svn --version`. I believe 3.2.5 came with svn 1.4, which is ancient and has many problems, so Ivor Prebeg's solution is probably the best answer.

Comment: @rlovtang I'm not sure exactly but your explanation does seem plausible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not downgrade server... You might break all of it

try to install separate svn client (with brew, macports, compile it?) on guy's Mac

Comment: +1. Trying to accommodate svn 1.4 is a nightmare, and it's much better to just use a newer client via brew, etc.

Comment: Thanks, based on the response, this approach seems like the best option.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing for the developer to do is to use the latest command line SVN client. Since the developer is getting the `client is too old to work with working copy` error, he has installed the command line tools with the new SVN client for sure; Xcode integration is merely a convenience, not a requirement.

You can integrate with the latest SVN using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425673/335858), but it uses a back door way of integrating SVN with XCode, and is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks, based on the response, this approach seems like the best option.